# Integrating $\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(4x^2+\pi^2)\sinh x} dx$ using residues

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(4x^2+\pi^2)\sinh x} dx$$
I'm stuck with this integral since I can't figure out the contour I should be using.

It doesn't fit in into standard ones like circle with a cut for integrals like
$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\ln  x}{polynomial} dx.$ Or infinite band for functions with imaginary period. I don't know what to do...

Comment: First, try to figure out where the poles are, that will give you some idea where contours should go.

Comment: @NinadMunshi There are infinitely many poles due to $sinh x$ so it must be some contour containig only finitely many of them with change of the integrals on the  sides that is controllable. But if I take a band that contains only one pole of this function that comes from $sinhx$ I can't compute how the integral on the upper side depends of my integral

Comment: But first, *where* are your poles, not how many.

Comment: @NinadMunshi On the imaginary axis

Comment: @NinadMunshi I tried that, rectangle would work perfectly if there was no $\frac{x}{4x^2+\pi^2}$ when I substitute value at $y=\pi$ it changes too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I managed to apply @NinadMunshi's idea here. 
We can try to compute an integral of the function $\frac{1}{(2z-\pi i)}\sinh(z)$ at the contour that is an infinite rectangle of height $\pi$ (let us denote it $\Gamma$). It has one simple pole inside and two on the boundary.

By comparing what we get on the real axis and on the line $\operatorname{Im}=\pi i$ we get the following identity:

\begin{gather}
\oint_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{(2z-\pi i)\sinh(z)}\,dz=\\\\\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2z-\pi i)\sinh(z)}\,dz+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(2z+\pi i)\sinh(z)}\,dz
=4\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{z}{(4z^2+\pi^2)\sinh(z)}\,dz=\\\\=2\pi i \operatorname{Res}_{\frac{\pi i}{ 2}}\frac{1}{(2z-\pi i)\sinh(z)}+ \pi i\bigg[\operatorname{Res}_{\pi i}\frac{1}{(2z-\pi i)\sinh(z)}-\operatorname{Res}_{0}\frac{1}{(2z-\pi i)\sinh(z)}\bigg]=\pi
\end{gather}

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sketch of a way forward.  The details are left to the reader.

First, note that the integrand is an even function.  Hence, we can write

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{(4x^2+\pi^2)\sinh(x)}\,dx=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x}{(4x^2+\pi^2)\sinh(x)}\,dx$$

---

Next, note that $\sinh(z)=0$ when $z=in\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.  So we choose a contour $C_N$ in the complex plane comprised of $(i)$ a straight line segment from $z=-(N+1/2)\pi$ to $z=(N+1/2)\pi$ and $(ii)$ a circular arc centered at $z=0$ and with radius $R_N=(N+1/2)\pi$.

Then, we evaluate the contour integral

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{C_N}\frac{z}{(4z^2+\pi^2)\sinh(z)}\,dz&=\int_{-(N+1/2)\pi}^{(N+1/2)\pi}\frac{x}{(4x^2+\pi^2)\sinh(x)}\,dx\\\\
&+\int_0^\pi \frac{i(N+1/2)^2\pi^2 e^{i2\phi}}{(4(N+1/2)^2\pi^2 e^{i2\phi})+\pi^2)\sinh((N+1/2)\pi e^{i\phi})}\,\,d\phi\tag1\\\\
&=2\pi i \text{Res}\left(\frac{z}{(4z^2+\pi^2)\sinh(z)}, z=i\pi/2\right)\\\\
&+2\pi i \sum_{n=1}^N \text{Res}\left(\frac{z}{(4z^2+\pi^2)\sinh(z)}, z=in\pi\right)\tag2
\end{align}$$

---

Show that as $N\to\infty$, the second integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ approaches $0$.  Then, evaluate the residues on the right-hand side of $(2)$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: Thank you very much, great solution. To show convergences to zero I can just apply Jordan's lemma and note that value of the residue at $i n \pi$ converges to zero, right?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: I'm not sure if Jordan's Lemma is applicable here, but you should be able to show that the integral approaches $0$ as $N\to\infty$.  I'm not sure what you meant by "the value of the residue at $in\pi$ converges to zero."  The value of the sum of the residues at $in\pi$ is not $0$.

Comment: I think I found a sollution that is a bit simpler than yours, I did it while trying to simplify the computation of the series in your sollution. I still think that your sollution is better since it is easier to find.